# strcmp saying that it has EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

This loop will crash and give the error of EXC_BAD_ACCESS in XCode 4.6.2

Here is the loop code

```
for (beforeToDel = studentToChange->pFirstClass; 
     (int)strcmp(beforeToDel->pNext->classId, className) == 0;
     beforeToDel = beforeToDel->pNext)
     {}
```

and the different variables have these values:

[image]

Thank you so much for any help you can give!

Comment: Check whether beforeToDel is null before using it in strcmp

Answer (score 2):

`beforeToDel->pNext->pNext` is `NULL`.  Your loop will crash on the second iteration trying to indirect through that pointer to compare to `className`.  You need to check it before calling `strcmp`.

Aside:  Why the typecast to `int`?

Comment: `beforeToDel->pNext->pNext` is `NULL` but `beforeToDel->pNext` is at an address that isn't `NULL`...  as for the typecast I was working with the debugger and it wanted me to cast it to an `int` before it would print so I thought I would give that a shot (it couldn't hurt right?) but I forgot to take it out before I posted it

Comment: Yes, that's true.  What are you trying to say?

Comment: It is crashing after the first iteration. That's why I am so confused because there is other code that catches that `NULL` exception.

Comment: I still don't get it - the problem is that after the first iteration, you've advanced `beforeToDel` to the next entry, and the loop condition check is going to crash things.

Comment: I guess I'm confused why strcmp is crashing it on the first iteration when `beforeToDel->pNext->classId` is the same as `className` I thought it would return a value of zero which is what I thought my loop was checking for.

Comment: Wow I feel really dumb.  the loop check should be that the `strcmp` method call is not equal to zero correct?

Comment: 1. I expect it is *not* crashing on the first iteration, given the debugger dump you've shown here.  2. Whether you want `==` or `!=` depends on what you're trying to do - you didn't really explain that, so it's hard to say.  Do you want the loop to exit when the strings match, or when they don't match?

Comment: I want the loop to exit when `beforeToDel->pNext` matches the `className`. The method is supposed to take a node out of a linked list with the matching `className` that the method call provides.

Comment: Then you probably want `!=`, yes.

Comment: okay so I gave that a shot and if I run it in XCode then it will "hang" kindof and it will just run.  I usually stop it after about 15 seconds or so.  It will run through 3 or 4 of the iterations then it will hang.  If I run it through terminal then it will go nuts and end up deleting more of the nodes than is even in it's scope.  Can I send you an email with the whole of the code and that might help give a bit more scope into the project?

Comment: If you have a specific programming related question, you can feel free to post it on this site.  We're not really here to do general purpose debugging of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need to cast the return value of `strcmp` to an `int`. It's already one.
2. What happens if `beforeToDel` is NULL, or if `beforeToDel->pNext` is NULL? If they point to *nothing*, then they can't have a `classId` or `pNext` member, right?

It is an error to use `strcmp` if you haven't included `<string.h>`, so make sure you have that included. I presume you're looking for the link to a node to be removed, hence the rather awkward identifier "beforeToDel". What happens if the head of the list is the node you want to remove? Why don't you start with a pointer to `studentToChange->pFirstClass` and iterate on the links, rather than the nodes? This will solve your head problem, and make your code more clear at the same time.

I'm going to declare my linked list like this:

```
struct list {
    struct list *next;
    char class_name[];
};
```

Declare a pointed to whichever type `pNext` is. Call it `link`, because this object will store a pointer to the *link* that the code will update. Initialise it to the head of the list. This way, when the first iteration results in a match, you'll be changing the head of your list with ease. In my function, I'll be returning the new head. You don't need to do that in your code. Just make sure `link` points to the head of the list (eg. `link = &studentToChange->pFirstClass;`).

At the end of each iteration, update `link` to point to `(*link)->next` (or `pNext`, in your case).

Operate on `*link`, rather than `link` (eg. `strcmp(*link->classId, class_name) == 0`). When the node to delete is found, assign over the top of it by using `*link = *link->next;` or equivalent.

```
struct list *list_remove_class_name(struct list *head, char *class_name) {
    struct list **link = &head;
                                                  /* Did you mean != 0 here? */
    while (*link != NULL && strcmp(*link->class_name, class_name) == 0) {
        *link = *link->next;
    }

    struct list *node = *link;
    if (node != NULL) {
        *link = node->next;
    }

    free(node);
    return head;
}
```